# How can I match two rows in a pyspark dataframe when the value in a column in a row matches the value in another column in another row?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe like below. If the value in col2 is found in other rows in col1, I want to get the values for col3 in a list in a new column. And I would rather not use self-join.

input:

```
col1    col2    col3  
A       B       1  
B       C       2
B       A       3
```

output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
A       B       1       [2,3]  
B       C       2       []
B       A       3       [1]
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a `join`? That's the idiomatic way to do this. Please back up the claim that join is an [expensive operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57484329/how-can-i-match-two-rows-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-when-the-value-in-a-column-in-a#comment101440689_57484519). Expensive relative to what?

Comment: relative to window operations.

Comment: @ pault… I was trying to do same with spark dataframe but self join was not working on col2&col1.. donnw whats happening. could you please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mapping using `groupby` and then use `merge`.

```
mapper = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).agg({'col3': list}).rename(columns={'col3':'col4', 'col1': 'col2'})
df.merge(mapper, on='col2', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2    col3    col4
0   A   B       1      [2, 3]
1   B   C       2      NaN
2   B   A       3      [1]
```

Comment: Thanks. Merging is essentially joining. Unfortunately joining is an expensive operation. Could there be windowing operation that has the same functionality?

Comment: Can you define "expensive"?

Comment: Joining takes more processing power than windowing operation. a slef-join could potentially be the answer here, but I was wondering it's possible to avoid joins in this matter.

Comment: I do not think "Joining takes more processing power than windowing operation" holds true in this case as the window is arbitrary. The window does not have a fix order or pattern. It is best to merge after a `mapper` @AhmadrezaJavanmardi